# Stage snapshot saving with webcam view and image is working after compilation but not working once the executive file's location is changed

Tags: actionscript-3, snapshot, bitmapdata, stage

package
{

import flash.display.DisplayObject;

```
import flash.display.IBitmapDrawable;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.net.FileFilter;
import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;
import com.adobe.images.PNGEncoder;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.BlendMode;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.filters.ColorMatrixFilter;
import flash.media.Camera;
import flash.media.Video;
import flash.display.Graphics;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLRequestHeader;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

import flash.display.DisplayObject;

import flash.geom.Matrix;

import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.geom.Point;



public class Main extends Sprite
{
    private var drawMatrix:Matrix;
    private var Mask2:Loader = new Loader();
    private var byteArray:ByteArray;
    private var jpg:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder();
    private var file:FileReference;
    private var cam : Camera = Camera.getCamera();
    private var vid : Video = new Video(640, 500);
    private var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(vid.width, vid.height); 
    private var bitmap:Bitmap ;
    private var fileReference:FileReference;

    public function Main()
    {
        initTracking();
    }

    private function initTracking() : void
    {
        var camW : int = 640;
        var camH : int = 500;

        // Create the camera

        cam.setMode(camW, camH, stage.frameRate);

        // Create a video

        vid.attachCamera(cam);  
        addChild(vid);

        Mask2.load(new URLRequest("button.png"));  
        addChild(Mask2);
        Mask2.y = 100;
        Mask2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, captureImage);
    }
```

private function captureImage(event:MouseEvent):void {

```
    bitmapData= new BitmapData(stage.width, stage.height)
    bitmapData.draw(stage, new Matrix());
   var bitmapDataA: BitmapData = new BitmapData(300, 250);
        bitmapDataA.copyPixels(bitmapData, new Rectangle(360, 20, 620, 540), new Point(0, 0));

    bitmap= new Bitmap(bitmapDataA);
                addChild(bitmap);
                bitmap.x = 0;
                bitmap.y = 556;
                bitmap.width = 105;
                bitmap.height = 80;
    }


            }

}
```

Comment: Can you clarify a little more on what is happening?

Comment: Thanks, Ascension Systems. I've modified my question and class in above. Please look at it this time and help me if possible.

Comment: when you say "executive file's location is changed" what exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: that mean the .swf file after compilation. currently, that doesn't matter. The main problem is to get a way to take a snapshot of the stage with webcam view and the button image...Based on my posted class is it possible? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Post the full class instead of snippits.
With what you posted all I can see is

```
//bitmapData is not defined
var byteArray:ByteArray = encoder.encode(bitmapData);
```

I have a feeling you are not accurate on the description of your issues.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I wanted to take a snapshot of my whole stage. With having this interest, I loaded the webcam and one image in the stage and what I want is to click the image to get a snapshot of the webcam view with the button image together.  Below is the class for your reference. [if I take "bitmapData.draw(vid, new matrix()); then it's working but if I take bitmapData.draw(stage, new matrix()); it's not working then]. Please help me to show any way to make it work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks, Ascension Systems and The_asMan. I've modified my question and class in above. Please look at it this time and help me if possible. Thanks a lot.